# Updating Child Entities Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, edmx

Hi Here here we another Entity Framework question and updating child entities. 

The scenario:
I have objects called Clients that have Assessments and Weekly Assessments.  Clients are created and saved fine however the Assessment (child entity) are not attaching and being added to the database.

```
     public SHAID.DataLayer.Client Save(SHAID.DataLayer.Client client)
    {
         System.Data.EntityKey key;
         object originalItem;

         using (_shaidEntities = new DataLayer.SHAIDEntities())
         {

             key = _shaidEntities.CreateEntityKey("Clients", client);

             if (_shaidEntities.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out originalItem))
             {

                 foreach (var item in client.Assessments)
                 {
                     if (item.Id == default(int))
                     {
                         item.Client.Id = client.Id;

                     }
                 }

                 _shaidEntities.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName, client);

                 //client.WeeklyAssessments.Load();
                 //client.Assessments.Load();
             }
             else
             {
                 _shaidEntities.AddToClients(client);
             }

             _shaidEntities.SaveChanges();

         }

        return client;
    }
```

The client object has the assessment attached and the client reference id is alreeady populated with the correct id
I have tried various solutions when i iterate over the collection of Assessments (AddObject, Attach) but each time the context complains it is already attached

Please help

Much appreciated

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this one out by creating new Assessments and adding them to the originalItem.  Editing existing Assessments were simple found in the the originalItem list and updated

Had to uncomment the client.WeeklyAssessments andclient.Assessments to get back filled Id's for the child entities